# How to view all items contained in QGraphicsScene?

Tags: qt4

is there an easy way to zoom the scene so, that all items are visible?
looks like a simple task, but I'am sitting since an hour on it. :-(

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `MyGraphicsView.fitInView(MyScene.rect())` replacing MyGraphicsView and MyScene with the correct names for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Valentin, you can use [QGraphicsView::scale()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qgraphicsview.html#scale) function to zoom the graphics view. Another way to do that is to use [QGraphicsView::setTransform()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qgraphicsview.html#setTransform) method passing QTransform object with a scale tranformation

Comment: I've done all that, but I guessed, there should be just one method. And indeed there is (s. answer from Arnold Spence). Thank you anyway!